# Laravel : query two `articles` tables,`id` conflict

Tags: mysql, laravel

For example,
there are two tables,`articles-1` and `articles-2`,
they have the same structure,each table's `id` is from `1`.

I want to query the two tables' articles and show them on one view.

ArticlesController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $articles1=Article1::all();
    $articles2=Article2::all();
    //$allArticles=;  //How to merge $articles1 and $articles2?
    return view('index', compact('allArticles'));
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<ul>
   @foreach ($allArticles as $article)
       <li><a href="articles/{{$article->id}}">{{ $article->title }}</a></li>
       <li>{{ $article->updated_at}}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

**Questions：**

1、In `ArticlesController`,How to merge `$articles1` and `$articles2`?

2、In view,every item has a link to `show` page (detail page), but they probably have the same `id`s ,what should I do?

---

**Update:**
How to write the query of `show` method?

ArticlesController.php

```
public function show($slug)
{
    //query twice?
    $newArticle = NewArticle::findOrFail($slug);
    $oldArticle = OldArticle::findOrFail($slug);

    //How to write next?

    return view('show', compact('article'));
}
```

Comment: If you have same column names in both table then just use query builder to get records of both table

Comment: @Sagar Gautam How to query both table? according to the docs,query one table is like this: `$users = DB::table('users')->get();` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: If you have same columns then you can union the two queries and finally execute the query to get data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should not have models like Article1 and Article2. Use some context specific name for model and table names. 
Now if we have two models let's say Oldarticle and Newarticle and tables oldarticles and newarticles then

```
public function index()
{
    $oldArticlesArr = Oldarticle::all()->toArray();
    $newArticlesArr = Newarticle::all()->toArray();
    $allArticles = array_merge($oldArticlesArr, $newArticlesArr);
    return view('index', compact('allArticles'));
}
```

Use a article_slug column in both newarticles and oldarticles table and create link as follows

```
<ul>
   @foreach ($allArticles as $article)
       <li><a href="articles/{{$article['article_slug']}}">{{ $article['title'] }}</a></li>
       <li>{{ $article['updated_at']}}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

For showing a single article from either table write the following method in ArticleController

```
public function show($article_slug)
{
    //search in oldarticles table
    $oldArticle = Oldarticle::where('article_slug',$article_slug)->first();
    if ($oldArticle) {
        //if found return that as article
        $article = $oldArticle;
        return view('show', compact('article'));
    } else {
        //search in newarticles table if found return that as article
        $article = Newarticle::where('article_slug',$article_slug)->first();
        if ($article) {
            return view('show', compact('article'));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks! How to write the `show` method? see my update.